# Page versus post ID specific CSS ID?

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the background color  Of the page below. I have had problems with identifying individual pages before – but perhaps something has changed. Any quick thoughts?

http://artbeyond.co/the-mcgladrey-art-gallery/gallery-photos/

```
.page-id-165 #wrapper {
background-color:#252525;
```

}

Comment: Please ensure that you have included the `body_class()` template tag inside your HTML `<body>` tag (e.g. `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`); otherwise, this question can't really be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function in your body tag to apply classes like "page-id-65"

```
<body <?php body_class() ?>>
```

Comment: yes thats right, css should show its effect.